# Batch script to run and close multiple programs at a specific time

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file

I need to create a batch script that runs at specific times a certain program and then close it after like 10 minutes. For example

```
4:10 PM - Run C:\1.exe
4:20 PM - Close C:\1.exe
4:25 PM - Run C:\2.exe
4:35 PM - Close C:\2.exe
```

How can I manage to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off 
start C:\myfolder\1.exe
wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\myfolder\\1.exe' delete
```

I don't know how to set the time to start and kill the process.

Comment: Hi there! Unfortunately, we're not a script writing service.  What have you got so far, and where exactly are you getting stuck implementing the script you want?  Also, why not just use the Task Scheduler built into Windows?

Comment: I updated my question with what I have so far

Comment: Use task scheduler or some other type of event scheduler to schedule what you want to do and when.

Comment: task scheduler seems not have option to kill the summoned program...

Comment: You need to do something like : `taskkill /f /im 1.exe` in a batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a scheduled PowerShell script like this one:

```
$process = Start-Process Notepad.exe -PassThru
Start-Sleep -Seconds (60 * 10)
Stop-Process -Id $process.Id
```

it starts a process, waits for 10min doing nothing and then stops the process.

Batch files are so 1980s, PowerShell is the way to do things today.

Comment: Thank you very much this was awesome! Solved the "specific time" issue adding this code at the start of the script: do {
Start-Sleep 1
}
until ((get-date) -ge (get-date "9:38 AM"))